# MySQL Select entries from last 2 days of specific week / month

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I got 2 columns, 'create_time' is when the account has been registered and 'last_play' is when the account has logged in the last time. I want to select accounts which have been registered in a specific week / month and have been active within the last 2 days of this specific week / month.

Here is how I select ALL entries of last week without considering last_play (works):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM account.account 
WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(create_time) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW()) - 1 
AND YEAR(create_time) = YEAR(NOW());
```

That's my current query for last week which doesn't work:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM account.account 
WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(create_time) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW()) - 1 
AND YEAR(create_time) = YEAR(NOW()) 
AND DATE(last_play) BETWEEN 
    ADDDATE(DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)), 
    INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(DATE(NOW())) DAY) 
    AND DATE(NOW());
```

Comment: It seems you made an edit while I was answering. Could you explain what you mean by "I want to select accounts which have been registered in a specific week / month and have been active within the last 2 days of this specific week / month." Do you mean saturday and sunday of that specific week?

Comment: I just edited my question to make the code more readable. Yes I mean saturday and sunday of that week. I'll test your query now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basing on your first working query, you can use the MySQL function `WEEKDAY` to identify saturdays and sundays:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM account.account 
WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(create_time) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW()) - 1 
AND YEAR(create_time) = YEAR(NOW())
AND WEEKOFYEAR(last_play) = WEEKOFYEAR(create_time)  //last_play is in the same week as create_time
AND WEEKDAY(last_play) IN (5,6);  //wekkday is saturday or sunday
```

This gives you entries which were active on the saturday or sunday in the same week they registered.

**EDIT:** For months, you basically do the same thing, but replace `WEEKOFYEAR` by `MONTH` and `WEEKDAY` by `DAYOFMONTH`. The last two days of a given month you can find manually by checing for all possible cases:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM account.account 
WHERE MONTH(create_time) = MONTH(NOW()) - 1 
AND YEAR(create_time) = YEAR(NOW())
AND MONTH(last_play) = MONTH(create_time)  //last_play is in the same MONTH as create_time
AND 
   (DAYOFMONTH(last_play) IN (30,31) AND MONTH(last_play) IN (1,3,5,7,8,10,12)
    OR DAYOFMONTH(last_play) IN (29,30) AND MONTH(last_play) IN (4,6,9,11)
    OR DAYOFMONTH(last_play) IN (27,28) AND MONTH(last_play) IN (2))
```

Never mind a leap year ;-). Or incorporate it again manually by yourself.

Comment: `last_play >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)` just goes 2 days back from now but I want to check on the last 2 days of that specific week.

Comment: Thanks that's what I needed! I still need to find a solution for months where you don't know which week days are the last 2 ones.